# Add labels to Google Cloud Dataflow (Apache Beam) at runtime

Tags: java, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

**TL;DR**: I am looking for something similar to Dataflow Flex *--additional-user-labels* but for "normal" Dataflow.

Hello there.

I have a custom dataflow pipeline in Apache Beam.

I know I can add labels to a pipeline as follow:

```
PipelineOptions customOptions = PipelineFactory.createCustomOptions(args);
  
customOptions.setLabels(ImmutableMap.of("foo", "bar"));
    
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(customOptions);
```

But is it possible to change it at runtime? I need to label some Google Cloud Dataflow though Airflow.  I actually pass many variable to the PipelineOptions but they are ValueProvider and their value is accessed/processed in runtime.
Can I do something similar to change the label when I run the dataflow job from Airflow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, for traditional or classic templates, this is only supported via the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#using-the-rest-api) based invocation by providing "additionalUserLabels" in the environment section. You can file a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) if you would like to request gcloud command to support it just like in [flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/run).